# Given the probability distribution of X, whats the PDF of X²?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, signal-processing

Let's say we have a random variable $X$ with a certain probability density function $f_x(x)$.

1) How should I find out the PDF of the random variable $X^2$?

Problem background:

$X_1 = s_1 + W$, where $W \sim \mathcal(0,\sigma^2)$ and $s_1 = A \cos(\phi)$ with $\phi \sim unif[-\pi,\pi]$ and $A$ a positive constant value. The pdf of $s_1$ is than $f_{s_1}(s_{1}) = \frac{1}{\pi \sqrt{A^2-s_1^2}}$. The pdf of $X_1$ can be described as:

\begin{equation}
f_{x_1}(x_1) = f_{s_1}(s_1)*f_w(w)
\end{equation}

Note the assumption that $s_1$ and $W$ are independent.

2) Any ideas for the analytical expression of $f_{x_1}(x_1)$?

By the way, the PDF of $X_1$ is attached below.
[image]

Let a second random variable be $X_2 = s_2 + W$, where $W \sim \mathcal(0,\sigma^2)$ and $s_2 = A \sin(\phi)$ with $\phi \sim unif[-\pi,\pi]$ and $A$ the same constant value as with $X_1$. The pdf of $s_2$ is than $f_{s_2}(s_{2}) = \frac{1}{\pi \sqrt{A^2-s_2^2}}$. The pdf of $X_2$ can be described the same way as before:

\begin{equation}
f_{x_2}(x_2) = f_{s_2}(s_2)*f_w(w)
\end{equation}

3) Any ideas for the PDF of $T = \sqrt{{X_1}^2+{X_2}^2}$?

Below is a plot of the PDFs of $X_1^2$ (blue) and $X_2^2$ (red).

[image: PDFs of $X_1$ in blue and $X_2$ in red, note the delay between them]

Surprisingly, the response to 3) seems to be a normal distribution... but why? Even the variable ${T}^2 = {X_1}^2+{X_2}^2$ seems to follow also a normal distribution. The delay between both PDFs of $X_1$ and $X_2$ seems to be **really** important, since $\sqrt{2{X_1}^2} = \sqrt{2} X_1$ **does** **not** follow a normal distribution. The result of 3) is plotted below.

[image]

Really appreciate your help, regards.

Comment: What is $Acos(x)$?  It can't be $\arccos x$, can it, with $x$ ranging from $-\pi$ to $\pi$?  Is $A$ a constant, and $s = A \cos x$?

Comment: Sorry, $A$ is a constant.

Comment: Do you mean $T^2 = X_1^2+X_2^2$, not $\sqrt{T}$?

Comment: Exactly, thanks

Comment: Since this problem statement has grown a lot, I have opened another topic asking the real question behind all these questions, which in fact is not that long. Really appreciate your help @BrianTung
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1267342/pdf-of-xt-ej-omega-c-twt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On 1):

For $x>0$ we have: $$F_{X^{2}}\left(x\right)=F_{X}\left(x^{\frac{1}{2}}\right)-F_{X}\left(-x^{\frac{1}{2}}\right)$$

Taking the derivative on both sides we find:

$$f_{X^{2}}\left(x\right)=\frac{1}{2}x^{-\frac{1}{2}}\left[f_{X}\left(x^{\frac{1}{2}}\right)+f_{X}\left(-x^{\frac{1}{2}}\right)\right]$$

Comment: Good! Since $f_x(x)$ is symetric, $f_x\Big(x^{\frac{1}{2}}\Big) = f_x\Big(x^{- \frac{1}{2}}\Big)$. So at the end we obtain: $f_{x^2}(x) = x^{- \frac{1}{2}} f_x\Big(x^{\frac{1}{2}}\Big)$, am I right?

Comment: By the way, I have updated the problem statement. Thanks for your help

Comment: If $f_X(x)$ is symmetric then you can indeed simplify the way you stated. You are welcome.

Comment: If I apply this expression for a random variable $X$ with a Rice distribution, i.e. $f_{X}(x) = I_0\bigg(\dfrac{x·\nu}{\sigma^2}\bigg)\dfrac{x}{\sigma^2} e^{-\dfrac{x^2+\nu^2}{2 \sigma}}$, I obtain $0$ as a result which I guess is NOT correct. Note that the modified Bessel function is symmetric.

Comment: I am not familiar with modified Bessel functions. If you are saying that $I_0(-x)=I_0(x)$ then the conclusion is that $f_X(-x)=-f_X(x)$ when it is defined as in your comment. This tells us that $f_X$ cannot serve as PDF on $\mathbb R$ (a PDF does not take negative values). It might serve as a PDF on $[0,\infty)$ but in that case it cannot be a symmetric PDF. For that you need $f_X(x)=f_X(-x)$ wich implies that the domain of the function must be symmetric w.r.t. $0$.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that a random variable $Y = X^2$ would have a PDF

$$
f_Y(y) = \frac{f_X(\sqrt{y})+f_X(-\sqrt{y})}{2\sqrt{y}} \qquad y \geq 0
$$

but I have to give that some thought to verify/disprove it.

Off the top of my head, I can't think of a short cut for the PDF of $Z = \sqrt{X_1^2+X_2^2}$ where both of $X_1, X_2$ independently share the PDF $f_X(x)$.  (Meaning integration is the path forward.)  But I'll also give that some thought, too.

Comment: Thanks, I have added a picture of the final result. It is based on empirical results.

Comment: The formula for the PDF of $X^2$ is a straight consequence of the Jacobian formula for changes of variable in integrals, as has been explained maaaany times on the site.

Comment: Sorry Did, 
didn't meant to repeat stuff, I am new here. Thanks for your contribution :)

Comment: Small thing, but for $y=0$ the mentioned expression is not defined.

Comment: @Did: That's not surprising.  But I still prefer to work those kinds of things out for myself if I can...

Comment: By the way, I have updated the problem statement. Thanks to you all for your help.

Comment: Since this problem statement has grown a lot, I have opened another topic asking the real question behind all these questions, which in fact is not that long. Really appreciate your help @drhab
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1267342/pdf-of-xt-ej-omega-c-twt

Comment: If I apply this expression for a random variable $X$ with a Rice distribution, i.e. $f_{X}(x) = I_0\bigg(\dfrac{x·\nu}{\sigma^2}\bigg)\dfrac{x}{\sigma^2} e^{-\dfrac{x^2+\nu^2}{2 \sigma}}$, I obtain $0$ as a result which I guess is NOT correct. Note that the modified Bessel function is symmetric.