# PDF of $|X(t)| =| e^{j\omega_c t}+W(t)|$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, signal-processing

let $X(t) = Ae^{j\omega_c t}+W(t)$, where $W(t)$ is a gaussian process that follows the statistics $W \sim \mathcal{CN}(0,\sigma^2)$ and $\omega_c$ denotes the carrier pulse frequency and $A$ is a positive constant value.

For $A>\sigma$, $ |X(t)|$ seems to follow a gaussian process, but as said in the comments, for lower $A$ values $|X(t)|$ does follow a Rician distribution.
Can someone proof this? Because $Ae^{j\omega_c t}$ could be understood as $Ae^{j\phi}$ where $\phi \sim unif[-\pi,\pi]$, and so it is not a constant value as it is said in the standard Rician distribution definition.

This is the histogram that I obtained with MATLAB for $A=1$ :
[image]

My MATLAB code is following:

```
fm = 10e3; % sampling rate
Tm = 1/(fm); % sampling time
t = (1:1:2e6)*Tm; % time vector
fc = 1e-2*fm; % carrier frequency
A = 1; % Amplitude
x = A*exp(1i*2*pi*fc*t); % signal

sigma = 2.5e-5; % noise variance
w = sigma/sqrt(2)*(randn(length(t),1) + 1i*randn(length(t),1))'; % noise vector
y_th = x+w; % received signal
hist(abs(y_th),200)
```

Comment: Is $W(t)$ complex or real? If $W(t)$ is complex Gaussian, $|X(t)|$ may not be Gaussian: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_distribution or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice_distribution However, if $W(t)$ is real, then, $|X(t)|$ can be Gaussian as $Ae^{jw_ct}$ is a constant term.

Comment: Hi, $W(t)$ is complex Gaussian. The final plot is the attached one, doesn't it seem like a Gaussian distribution?

Comment: How did you generate random variable $W(t)$?

Comment: @Frey The question is now updated, Matlab code included. I have generated $W(t)$ as $W(t) = W_R(t) + jW_I(t)$, where $W_R, W_I \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\frac{\sigma^2}{2})$

Comment: In general it is not Gaussian, You can see it when you substitute small $A$, e.g., $A = 2.8e-10$. Here you can see the difference as well: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice_distribution

Comment: Hi @Frey, you are totally right. For scenarios with SNR = 0 and below $|X|$ does not seem to follow a normal distribution. However if I assume that it is still normal and compute $T = \sum_{n=1}^N |X_n|^2 $, where $ |X_n|$ follow the same statistic than $X$, the resulting variable $T$ matches pretty well a noncentral chi squared distribution. I will work it a bit and tell you soon. Appreciate your help.

Comment: You are welcome. Please note that even in real case, it may not be Gaussian as well :)